# Converting x-www-form-urlencoded query string to a dict

Tags: python, forms

Given a query string from x-www-form-urlencoded form data.

```
data[foo]=bar&data[bar]=baz
```

I'd like to translate it into a Python dict such as

```
{'data': {'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 'baz'}}
```

Or something close to that. Basically, something akin to the way this form data would be handled in PHP's $_POST variable:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [foo] => bar
            [bar] => baz
        )

)
```

But urlparse.parse_qs() just gives me:

```
{'data[bar]': ['baz'], 'data[foo]': ['bar']}
```

It's not the end of the world. I can easily call the values from the dict as `data[bar]` or whatever. I guess I'm just a bit surprised that there isn't a module that performs this kind of parsing, at least that I could find. Does anybody know of one?

Bonus question: Is there perhaps a *reason* why such a library does not exist in Python, e.g. that PHP's translation of form data into a multiple layer array is wrong somehow?

Comment: Did you get the answer? I'm stucking in this situation right now and trying to find a library to parse it into a 'real' python `dict`, or I might have to convert it manually with ugly codes..

Answer (score 0):

Currently using this to manually converting it into 'real' python `dict`.
However, there still might be unknown problems that I haven't met yet.

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

str_raw_data = str(bytes_raw_data, 'utf-8')   # bytes to string

formatted_data_dict = parse_qs(str_raw_data)
data = {}
for k, v in formatted_data_dict.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        data[k] = v[0]
    else:
        data[k] = v

return data
```

Answer (score -3):

- PHP automatically decodes indexed form variables to deep level arrays. [PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php#87650)
- This is php feature, not a http or web standard.
- Because there is no common "Array" structure defines in HTTP RFC.
- And, using [] or other non-alphanumeric characters for key-string is really a bad habit

**So, we'd better just use flat key=value format**

- Or try code/decode multi-level arrays by user-define data format (as PHP does), for both client and server sides.
- if u offer a http api with this user-defined format, u have to explain a lot to your customers.